# Getting error while installing the setup of magento2 on ubuntu?

Tags: magento-2.0

[when i'm entering the domain-name or IP on the browser for setup of magento2, then its shows me this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJsL6.png)

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 0):

1. please check htaccess file. Rename htaccess file then again check.
2. check your php install or not. If installed then check its version beacuse magento 2.0 version working on 7.0.2 php.

[check here requirement](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)